# What are some of your best iTunes add-ins?

Tags: itunes

I realized recently that iTunes has add-ins.

What are the add-ins that add value to iTunes on Windows?

One add-in per answer please.

Answer (score 2):

[Doug's Scripts](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/) is a fantastic collection of AppleScripts for iTunes that perform a whole array of functions. I've often made us of them to help detect duplicate songs and just generally keep my music library neat and tidy.

Answer (score 1):

When I edit my mp3 tags with external tools, then I use [needledrop](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=needledrop) to force iTunes to refresh its internal database with updated tags content (by playing each file a few seconds).